# Dynamic properties for classes in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, metaprogramming

I am a vb.net newbie, so please bear with me. Is it possible to create properties (or attributes) for a class in visual basic (I am using Visual Basic 2005) ? All web searches for metaprogramming led me nowhere. Here is an example to clarify what I mean.

```
public class GenericProps
    public sub new()
       ' ???
    end sub

    public sub addProp(byval propname as string)
       ' ???
    end sub
end class

sub main()
  dim gp as GenericProps = New GenericProps()
  gp.addProp("foo")
  gp.foo = "Bar" ' we can assume the type of the property as string for now
  console.writeln("New property = " & gp.foo)
end sub
```

So is it possible to define the function addProp ?

Thanks!
Amit

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to modify a class at runtime with new properties<sup>1</sup>.  VB.Net is a static language in the sense that it cannot modify it's defined classes at runtime.  You can simulate what you're looking for though with a property bag.

```
Class Foo
  Private _map as New Dictionary(Of String, Object) 
  Public Sub AddProperty(name as String, value as Object)
    _map(name) = value
  End Sub
  Public Function GetProperty(name as String) as Object
    return _map(name)
  End Function
End Class
```

It doesn't allow direct access in the form of myFoo.Bar but you can call myFoo.GetProperty("Bar").

<sup>1</sup> I believe it may be possible with the profiling APIs but it's likely not what you're looking for.

Comment: Serializing that could be fun.

Comment: @Angry Jim, anytime object is involved, serialization is a risky proposition.

Comment: @JaredPar - This is good and might work for me. BTW I do not have a hard requirement to use existing class. I am okay with creating the class dynamically. I looked at System.Reflection.Emit yesterday and it was eye opening!

--Amit

Answer (score 1):

Came across this wondering the same thing for Visual Basic 2008.

The property bag will do me for now until I can migrate to Visual Basic 2010:

http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2010/01/20/fun-with-dynamic-objects-doug-rothaus.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No - that's not possible. You'd need a Ruby like "method_missing" to handle the unknown .Foo call. I believe C# 4 promises to offer something along these lines.